# How do I render Django queryset to javascript in template?

Tags: javascript, django, fullcalendar

So I'm working on a scheduler-like app with Django. I have `fullcalendar-django` library in my template, and making some changes with JavaScript. But then I ran into an issue. Here's my views.py

```
from .models import NewEvent

def ScheduleMain(request):
    allDays = NewEvent.objects.all()

    return render(request, 'main.html', {'allDays':allDays}
```

Let's say there are two fields in my model `NewEvent` - date(DateField) and event(CharField). 
Here's the  tag in my template.

```
{% block extrahead %}
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    for (each in allDays) {
    $(function() {
        if ($('.fc-day').attr('data-date') == "{{each.date}}") {
        $('.fc-day .fc-day-content').html("{{each.event}}")
        }
    });
    }
});
</script>
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
...
{% calendar %}
...
{% endblock %}
```

So in the `{% calendar %}`, each date is written in this way :

```
...
<td class="fc-day" data-date="2020-05-17">
    <div class="fc-day-content">today schedule comes here</div>
</td>
<td class="fc-day" data-date="2020-05-18">
    <div class="fc-day-content">today schedule comes here</div>
</td>
...
```

As you can see, I'm trying to fill in the "today schedule comes here" with whatever the event the user inputs. And of course, since the template is pre-designed, I cannot directly make changes to it. So I'm trying to work on it with JavaScript. And let's for now say there can only be one event per day. 
What have I done wrong? Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write the for loop in django template language instead of javascript.

```
{% block extrahead %}
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    {% for day in allDays %}

      $(function() {
        if ($('.fc-day').attr('data-date') == "{{day.date}}") {
          $('.fc-day .fc-day-content').html("{{day.event}}")
        }
      });

    {% endfor %}

});
</script>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Well I've tried this, but it gives me red underline on the template tag. What's wrong?

Comment: Or do I have to use JSON here? I'm not very familiar with it.

Comment: You may be seeing red underlines because IDEs can sometimes get confused when javascript is mixed up with django templatetags. What do you see when the page loads? and/or what does the javascript resolve to? You shouldn't need to use JSON here since all the info you need will be passed thorugh the context.